# UITableViewCell subclass, wrong height until scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, height, autolayout

I have a custom uitableviewcell in which I use a UIImageView. I want the cell to be able to resize its height according to a certain aspect ratio, based on the imageview width, but I keep getting these constraints problems:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffe13c14130 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffe117fb920(44)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffe13c15090 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7ffe13c11c10]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffe117fb920 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffe13c150e0 V:[UIView:0x7ffe13c11c10]-(0)-[UIButton:0x7ffe117e8110]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffe13c15190 V:[UIButton:0x7ffe117e8110(30)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffe13c151e0 V:[UIButton:0x7ffe117e8110]-(0)-[UIView:0x7ffe13c11d00]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffe13c15910 UIView:0x7ffe13c11d00.height == UIView:0x7ffe13c11c10.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffe13c15960 V:[UIView:0x7ffe13c11d00]-(0)-[UIButton:0x7ffe13c0b000]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffe13c159b0 UIButton:0x7ffe13c0b000.height == UIButton:0x7ffe117e8110.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffe13c15a50 V:[UIButton:0x7ffe13c0b000]-(0)-[UIView:0x7ffe13c11df0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffe13c15aa0 UIView:0x7ffe13c11df0.height == UIView:0x7ffe13c11c10.height>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffe13c15af0 V:[UIView:0x7ffe13c11df0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffe117fb920 )>"
```

My constraints are

```
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[s1(>=10)][pictureView][s2(==s1)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[s3][markAsFavorite(==30)][s4(==s3)][markForDeletion(==markAsFavorite)][s5(==s3)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[s1][s3]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[pictureView][s3]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[s2][s3]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[pictureView]-10-[markAsFavorite(==30)]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[pictureView]-10-[markForDeletion(==30)]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[pictureView][s5]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict]];
    [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[pictureView][s4]-10-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:dict]];


    photoHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:pictureView
                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                               relatedBy:0
                                                  toItem:nil
                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                              multiplier:1
                                                constant:(5*pictureView.frame.size.width)/16];


    [self.contentView addConstraint:photoHeight];
```

These constraints are added only once, in the updateConstraints method of the cell subclass. In the "drawRect" method I update the "photoHeight" constant and force a layout update.

The Result:
At first load, the cells look pretty bad, but after I scroll they update their height and look as expected. I think the problem is with the "photoHeight" constant not being updated when the cell is first loaded, but I don't know how to fix it taking into consideration that it depends on the imageview's width.
Can you help solve this problem?

I attached you some screenshots: 
Before scrolling
[image: before scrolling]

After scrolling
[image: after scrolling]

As you can see in the first screenshot, the image gets out of cells contentview, because the cell is to small for that image...but, after scrolling the cells are resized correctly. I want them to be resized from the beginning, not only after scrolling.

Comment: in which method did you add constrains?

Comment: -updateConstraints method of the UITableViewCell subclass. (I add them only when this method is called for the first time)

Comment: I have this same issue. I've been fighting with this same concept in various forms since early Xcode 6 beta. Have you resolved it yet?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was causing my version of this.

I was assigning values too late in the cell's lifecyle. As I dequeued the cell, I was setting a property for the cell's model, and then deferring the assignment of the UIViews (UILabels, in my case) until `layoutSubviews()`. This ended up causing an issue where the dimensions were all calculated before I actually set the text of the UILabels.

I recommend doing all the display setup at the time you dequeue the cell:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCustomCell
    cell.setUpAllTheThings(myTableDataz[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    //calc height
    return height;
}
```

Comment: I'm using self-sizing cells in iOS 8 using : table.estimatedRowHeight = 120;
table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

Comment: According to the documentation the cells should automatically evaluate constraints and set the necessary height

Comment: I attached some screenshots